# Core Data: how can I tell if child object has parent?

Tags: swift, relationship, predicate

I'm working on a songwriting app in SwiftUI. In it, there is a screen with all of one's individual lyrics. Some will have relationships to songs that they are part of, some will just be random lyrics without relationships. I would like to be able to filter that list based on whether there is a parent object or not but I don't see any obvious way of doing that in the predicate. Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Why don't you fetch the parent entity instead?

Comment: If you need to find elements whose parent association is empty, `NSPredicate(format: "parent == nil")` should do it?

Comment: check the parent relationship variable for nil

Comment: NSPredicate(format: "songs == nil") crashes with: Thread 1: "to-many key not allowed here" but I have a feeling it is due to the fact that this is a many to many relationship and I should probably make it one to many just to simplify things. Thanks, I think I can figure it out from there.

Comment: For a one to many, e.g. album->songs usually the song would have an inverse relation for the songs called album. Then you can query for songs that have album==nil